# How to search in a mysql database with variables

Tags: php, mysql, database, variables, pdo

Somebody can login. If he login, the entered password (decoded) will be compared with the right passwort (also decoded)
But if I make

```
$sql = "SELECT PasswordDecode FROM Userinformations WHERE Username = ".$Username;
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
        $PasswordDecode = $row["Password decode"];
    }
```

this error comes:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in ...

I don't understand. If the username is  `DumbUsername` and I make

```
$sql = "SELECT PasswordDecode FROM Userinformations WHERE Username = DumbUsername";
```

No error happend and it works. But if I write the Username in a variable, it dowsn't work. Why?
Please answer.

Comment: `SELECT PasswordDecode FROM Userinformations WHERE Username = DumbUsername` is invalid SQL, strings need to be quoted. This also opens you to SQL injections, use parameterized queries, this will take care of the quoting as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your query, use quotes arround variable

```
  $sql = "SELECT PasswordDecode FROM Userinformations WHERE Username = '$Username'";
```